# Novacode DocX with SaveFileDialogue C#

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

Good Day!

I want to know if it's possible to show `SaveFileDialogue` when saving .docx file using `Novacode DocX`?

Sample:

```
string fileName = @"D:\Users\John\Documents\DocXExample.docx";
var doc = DocX.Create(fileName);
doc.InsertParagraph("This is my first paragraph");        
doc.Save();
```

Where shoud I put the `SaveFileDialogue` code?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();` inside some button event handler which lets the user save the document. Double-click on the `SaveFileDialog` icon in your Visual Studio designer window as well to add the FileOk event handler and within event handler, put your code like this:

```
    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       var doc = DocX.Create(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
       doc.InsertParagraph("This is my first paragraph");        
       doc.Save();
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: IT WORKS HAHAHAHA THANK YOU!!! @m-adeel-khalid I've been searching for this about less than a month

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

```
private void btn_approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save As";
 saveFileDialog1.Filter = "DocX|*.docx";

   if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      var doc = DocX.Create(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
      doc.InsertParagraph("This is my first paragraph");        
      doc.Save();                         
   }
}
```